# Can a user be excluded from /etc/profile.d scripts?

Tags: linux, ssh, bash, rsync, profile

I am having a problem using Rsync/SSH with a specific user for Amanda backups on a server.

`rsync -e 'ssh -i /var/lib/amanda/.ssh/id_rsa_amdump' -az otherserver:/dir/to/copy /copy/dir`

I have noticed that it gives all kinds of errors on a script within /etc/profile.d and cannot log on with the SSH key. If I try to log into the user account with SSH it just displays errors and will not give a prompt. Is there a way to tell the user to not read /etc/profile.d or to set it to skip/exclude that user?

The errors it gives on log on attempt with SSH  is:

`/etc/profile.d/somescript.sh line 125: bind: warning: line editing not enabled`

It shows this error for at least 20 different lines inside the script. I do not get this error for any other user. In addition the home directory for the Amanda backup user is in `/var/lib/` not `/home`.

Comment: I imagine the best solution may be to simply fix the error in the scripts. It's surprising that the specific user can't log on but others can. Do they have a different shell configured?

Comment: What are the error messages ?

Comment: What's line 125 of somescript.sh ?

Comment: `bind -x '"\e[M":'$'"ls -l"';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `bind` only makes sense in a interactive shell. In somescript.sh [check if the shell is interactive](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Is-this-Shell-Interactive_003f.html) and only run `bind` if it is. For example,

```
if [ -n "$PS1" ]; then
    bind -x '"\e[M":'$'"ls -l"';
fi
```

Comment: An alternate test is `if tty -s; then ...`.